# How to show chinese character in java

Tags: java

How to show chinese character from result database

```
try
        {
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.268.0.154:1521:dbbd","ASCD","knj76yt");
             Statement st=con.createStatement();
             System.out.println("connection established successfully...!!");     

             ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from users  WHERE ROWNUM <51");

             pw.println("<table border=1>");
                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                    String numbr= rs.getString(1);
                     String nm_eng= rs.getString(2);
                     String nm_chinese= new String(rs.getString(3).getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); 
              pw.println("<tr><td>"+numbr+"</td><td>"+nm_eng+"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+nm_chinese+"</td></tr>");
              System.out.println(nm_chinese);

                 }
             pw.println("</table>");
             pw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: in nm_chinese show ????
please help

Comment: now what output you getting?

Comment: What IDE you are using? If you need to show the result in a `JLabel` you can set Chinese Font.

Comment: Does your database support or handle Chinese characters correctly when you input data into it? Considering the field is labeled as "iso-8859-1"

Comment: If you aren't sure exactly what's in `nm_chinese`, I would suggest that yo stop in your debugger after that value has been computed and look at what's actually in there.  Alternately, you could convert the value to printable Hex and look at it that way.

Comment: I use Eclipse..
the chinese show in System.out.println(nm_chinese);
but not in "<td>"+nm_chinese+"</td>

Comment: Have you tried `String nm_chinese = rs.getString(3);`?  If the database table is defined correctly, it should handle Chinese characters without issue.

Comment: yes..
at the first I put like that..
but Show ???? tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to show Chinese output,

```
        OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

        String chineseFromCode = nm_chinese;
        bufferedWriter.write(chineseFromCode);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
```

Comment: How is this any different than `System.out.println(nm_chinese);`? - Are you trying to get UTF-8 to be output instead of full Unicode?  How would that help?

Comment: System.out.println(nm_chinese); this is work, showing the chracter..
but for printIn show question tag...